# YoutubeVideoPlayer plugin not working iOS

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, plugins, ionic3

Hi I want use native `YoutubeVideoPlayer` from ionic.

I have added with this

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player
npm install --save @ionic-native/youtube-video-player
```

And in my component.html I have this :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let video of videos" class="youtube-video-cell"
(tap)="youtube.openVideo(video?.id?.videoId ? video?.id?.videoId : video?.id)">
```

I have added in provider for `app.module` and I declared it in my constructor.

When I click on my youtube video I have this message in my console :

```
Install the YoutubeVideoPlayer plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player'
```

I see him in my `config.xml`

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player" spec="2.1.0" />
```

Can you help me ?